# How to align matching values in two columns in Google Sheets, and bring along associated values in other columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of customer addresses that are randomized, with it are additional values that are attached to the order (Name, Order Value, etc).

Once I put the addresses through an optimal delivery map router, I paste the proper sequence into the sheet and would like the original address to match

Col A - Optimal addresses

Col B - Randomized addresses

Col C - Order info #1 (attached to Col B address)

Col D - Order info #2 (attached to Col B address)

**Task:** Match location of Column B values to Column A values, bringing over column C-D values with them.

```
Col A            Col B         Col C    Col D
10 john st    22 rowen ct       $11     X item 
1 park st    100 arrow dr       $12     Y item
22 rowen ct    10 john st       $15     Z item
100 arrow dr    1 park st       $17     J item
```

Answer (score 0):

E2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,B2:D,{1,2,3},0)))
```

A2 is the search parameter, B2 is the search column, while the :D after B2 extends the reference, and then {1,2,3} references each of those columns B,C,D and makes columns to the right of the column with the formula.  If you did B2:B instead, {1,2,3} will return errors for column 2 and 3, so extend it to B2:D so that 1=B, 2=C, 3=D. And the final 0 states that the columns are not sorted.

Comment: This would be better with some explanation of what is happening and why this is the correct answer.

Comment: If you type this in google sheets, documentation pops right up.  I would add: A2 is the serach parameter, B2 is the search column, while the :D after B2 extends the reference, and then {1,2,3} references each of those columns B,C,D and makes columns to the right.

Comment: @iateadonut Feel  free to edit it in. Thanks